# CSS scope in Visual Studio for Windows 8.1 apps

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I'm doing the following tutorial to learn about developing Windows store apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986964.aspx

in `step 5` it talks about why its registering event handlers in the `.js` file vs the `.html` file; its a precaution to avoid declaring global variables.

However later in `step 6` its discussing how to style your application using `css`.  it uses

```
#greetingOutput {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

My question is:  Is the CSS scoped only to your application, or is it global like the `javascript` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of global that they're using in reference to the JS variables is not the one you might be familiar with from app development. A "global" JS variable is still only scoped to the current page of the application -- as soon as you move away from that, it disappears.

As for the CSS, it's global in the sense that any page that includes that css file will have access to all of those identifiers throughout the page.